# Rotation of objects when object is not aligned to xyz

Tags: modeling, animation

thx in advance - I have an space station with 6 parts and I want to have several of the parts rotate around a central spine.  The space station is situated properly in space but it is not aligned to any standard axis (xyz).  I thought I could use local rotation to define an xyz for this object but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  I effectively want to define one (or more) rotation points for various pieces so that they all rotate correctly and relative to one another, which is all offset from standard xyz.  Please advise.

[image]

The solar fins needs to rotate around the spine line of the station.  The other parts need to do the same but at different speeds.

Comment: I’m not sure why the images aren’t working, but they aren’t right now. Anyway, this seems to be a simple matter of either using an armature, or parenting “without inverse.” That will create a local rotation space for the desired parts. You might add Emptys for location reference.

Comment: Looks like this was answered [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/224276/117774).

Answer (score 1):

1.) for every of your "rotation points" just add an empty.

2.) Then make this empty as parent of your object you want to rotate.

3.) Then rotate the empty as you like and your object will follow.

Repeat step 2-3 for every object you wanna rotate.

if you need more detailed explanation, let me know.