# How do I rotate an object around a non-global axis in Blender?

Tags: modeling, objects, animation-nodes

In Blender 2.92, if I have a propeller that needs to be rotated at a constant speed around an axis that is no either X,Y or Z.

How is it done?

Comment: I understand your question like you want to know how to change the rotation axis - but you specifically mention "constant speed". Do you have an issue with this, too? Then I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No issue with the speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually a propeller isn't rotating in free space - it's attached to something, like a plane for example or at least a motor. So if you animate your propeller spinning on the X, Y or Z axis and you parent it to something with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then the rotation will be relative to the parent object. If you don't want a plane or any other object visible in the render, parent the propeller to an Empty.

Comment: Ok, I get the idea. Thanks very much.